# change background Image on click using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I change the background image using jQuery?

It should change the image provided in my HTML. The function should be dynamic to change any image when called.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit. What have you tried so far? Anything we can go off of?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following code...

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='some location'>
</div>
```

You can change the image with the following jquery code...

```js
function change_image(){
  
  $("#container").html("<img src='some other image location'>");
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you said you are new to jQuery, I paid extra attention on commenting the code. You didn't really specify how the background image should be set, so I used a click event on thumbnails.

**The code:**

```
// before doing our magic with jQuery,
// we must wait for the dom to be ready to be manipulated
$(document).ready(function () {

    // listen for a click on any img inside the .images
    $('.images img').on('click', function () {

        // inside the event handlers callback, THIS refers to the img that was clicked
        // here we save the src property of the clicked img to a variable
        var imgSrc = $(this).prop('src');

        changeBackgroundImg(imgSrc);
    });

});

function changeBackgroundImg(imgSrc) {
    // we can set any css property to an element with jQuerys .css()
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ebd5q7h/1/).

**Links to documentation related to the code:**

- [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
- [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)